# Solve the ODE $y' = \frac{1}{e^{4y}+2x}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the ODE $$y' = \frac{1}{e^{4y}+2x}$$

It seems to have something to do with the roles of the independent and dependent variables, but I still can't solve it.

Comment: You might want to add 'please' in your post.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{e^{4y}+2x}$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=e^{4y}+2x$$
now we can write in another way
$$x'-2x=e^{4y}$$
this is linear first order equation (but respect to $y$ not to $x$)
$$x'+g(y)x=R(y)$$ 
so that 
$$g(y)=-2$$
$$R(y)=e^{4y}$$
you can solve respect to $y$